# emerge cannot prevent installing as it cannot find the package name

Tags: package-management, gentoo, emerge

Gentoo emerge cannot find name of package
In attempt to prevent the installation of `dev-python/setuptools-53.0.0` failed

```
emerge: error: Invalid Atom(s) in --exclude parameter: 'dev-python/setuptools-53.0.0' (only package names and slot atoms (with wildcards) allowed)
```

Where is the mistake, please show the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you included in your question states:

> only package names and slot atoms (with wildcards) allowed

What you provided is `dev-python/setuptools-53.0.0`. This is an invalid package specification (atom) in Gentoo. It is closest to the range/equality atom which would be written `=dev-python/setuptools-53.0.0`.

However, according to that error message, an exact version specification is not allowed for the `--exclude` parameter. If you want to entirely disallow `setuptools` of any version to be included for this single `emerge` call, you may specify `--exclude dev-python/setuptools` instead. `dev-python/setuptools` is not “slotted”, so you cannot be more exact than that.

### Preventing Installation of a Specific Package Version

If you need to explicitly disallow installation of precisely `=dev-python/setuptools-53.0.0`, you may instead use `package.mask`. You may find and edit (or create) this file, depending on your system, at one of the following locations:

- `/etc/portage/package.mask/package.mask` (here there is a folder named `/etc/portage/package.mask` and all files inside of that folder will be loaded as mask entries by portage. I normally just create a file also named `package.mask` in that folder, but it is at your discretion).
- `/etc/portage/package.mask` (here, instead of a folder, there is just a single file).

You may edit this file to indicate which versions of the package you want to mask. Once you do this, it will cause portage to exclude that package from consideration. However, this may make it impossible to install certain packages.

If you do mask that package using this method, you should prefix the mask with comments describing why you placed it in the mask file. When an `emerge` call would exit with failure due to the mask, it will display your comment, reminding you why you had masked the package and helping you to decide if you want to unmask it at that point.

Example `package.mask` entry masking all 53.0 versions (including 53.0.0, 53.0.1, etc.):

```
# Mask dev-python/setuptools-53.0* because it has some bug which isn’t present
# in setuptools-51* and which should be fixed in setuptools-53.1*.
=dev-python/setuptools-53.0*
```

Another example, matching exactly 53.0.0 (when 53.0.1 comes out, that will start being allowed):

```
# Mask dev-python/setuptools-53.0.0 because it has a bug which breaks things for me
# which should be fixed in dev-python/setuptools-53.0.1 when that’s released.
=dev-python/setuptools-53.0.0
```

For a more comprehensive explanation of the syntax of atoms, please see [ebuild(5)](https://dev.gentoo.org/%7Ezmedico/portage/doc/man/ebuild.5.html). For further details on `package.mask`, please see [portage(5)](https://dev.gentoo.org/%7Ezmedico/portage/doc/man/portage.5.html) and search for `package.mask` under the section for `/etc/portage/`.